# Eclipse Maven runtime dependencies and profiles

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven-3

Im trying to understand maven profiles and have run into the following issue.

This is my simplified example, I have two maven projects, project A and Project B.

project A has a compile time maven dependency on project B.

project B includes a runtime dependency (lets say to project C) when the maven profile "TEST" is active.

so the problem is the class path generated when I run project A. it doesn't have project C in it, even though the TEST profile is active for project A.

this is using eclipse Helios service release 1, Maven Integration for Eclipse plugin vrs 0.10.2.20100623-1649

any ideas?

Comment: What does this have to do with eclipse? HAve you run mvn help:effective-pom, or dependency:tree, or just with -X?

Comment: The reason for the eclipse tag was i was not sure if it was an eclipse plugin issue or a maven issue. thanks for letting me know about the effective-pom command it seems that its maven that doesnt transfer the runtime dependency from project B to project As effective pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems dependencies that are within profiles of dependent projects (transitive) dont give there runtime dependencies to the person who depends on them, This seems strange.

A work around was to add the profiles (containing the dependencies) to a parent then the children inherit the dependencies.

i.e. introduce a parent to A, I could have put them directly in A as YMomb kindly suggested. but its the inheritance aspect of this issue I needed to resolve as I have lots of projects As.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that profiles are the best way to handle with TEST.

The use of profile to change dependecies will change the POM of the generated project.
If you install Project B with TEST activated, the runtime dependency will be added. (Whatever project A profile).

Optional dependencies are not added by transitivity. You need to add the dependency in project A.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in Eclipse using m2eclipse 0.12.x. The second project pom.xml look like this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>TEST</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.test</groupId>
          <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Then I set profile TEST as an active on Maven panel in the project properties dialog and made sure dependency resolution from Workspace is enabled there.

After that you can run any classes from test2 project's `src/main/java` and generated classpath looks like this:

```
C:\Dev\Java1.6\bin\javaw.exe -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
   -classpath C:\Dev\Workspace\test2\target\classes;C:\Dev\Workspace\test1\target\classes org.test2.Test2
```

Note, that dependencies with runtime scope only works for "Java Application" launch configuration type in Eclipse, but not for "JUnit" launch configuration, which uses different classpath resolver provided by m2eclipse's JDT integration.

Comment: looking at your class path you seem to have proven that profiles work between two projects. i.e. you are running Test2 and proven that it depends on test1 when the profile is active, yep this isn't a problem. The issue I have is test2 has a normal dependency on test1 and test1 has a profiled dependency on something else. then rerun the code in test 2.